# Simple Regular Expression (Regex) issue (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to use a .NET Regex to validate the input format of a string. The string can be of the format

```
single digit 0-9 followed by
single letter A-Z OR 07 OR 03 or AA followed by
two letters A-Z
```

So 0AAA, 107ZF, 503GH, 0AAAA are all valid. The string with which I construct my Regex is as follows:

```
    "([0-9]{1})" +
    "((03$)|(07$)|(AA$)|[A-Z]{1})" +
    "([A-Z]{2})"
```

Yet this does not validate strings in which the second term is one of 03, 07 or AA. Whilst debugging, I removed the third term from the string used to construct the regex, and found that input strings of the form 103, 507, 6AA WOULD validate.......

Any ideas why, when I then put the third term back into the Regex, the input strings such as 1AAGM do not match?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: FYI, I found this tool really useful to test regex http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because your expression requires the strings with `03`, `07` and `AA` to end right there (`$` matches the end of input). Remove the `$` from these sub-expressions, and move it to the end of the expression.

```
"^[0-9](03|07|AA|[A-Z])[A-Z]{2}$"
```

Comment: +1, while my answer does explain what he was doing and offered a solution. This answer ensures that 107ZFD, for example will not validate, while mine would match to the 107ZF portion of the string. Not sure which is what he is wanting, but this is also a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is because you are using the "$" in the regex, which means in this case to assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character). Remove it and it should work. From [Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), here is what you were doing:

```
([0-9]{1})((03$)|(07$)|(AA$)|[A-Z]{1})([A-Z]{2})
```

> ```
> Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks
>
> Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([0-9]{1})»
>    Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1}»
>       Exactly 1 times «{1}»
> Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «((03$)|(07$)|(AA$)|[A-Z]{1})»
>    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(03$)»
>       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(03$)»
>          Match the characters “03” literally «03»
>          Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
>    Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(07$)»
>       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «(07$)»
>          Match the characters “07” literally «07»
>          Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
>    Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(AA$)»
>       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 5 «(AA$)»
>          Match the characters “AA” literally «AA»
>          Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
>    Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[A-Z]{1}»
>       Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{1}»
>          Exactly 1 times «{1}»
> Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 6 «([A-Z]{2})»
>    Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{2}»
>       Exactly 2 times «{2}»
> ```

Followed by the revised version:

```
([0-9]{1})((03)|(07)|(AA)|[A-Z]{1})([A-Z]{2})
```

> ```
> Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks
>
> Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([0-9]{1})»
>    Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1}»
>       Exactly 1 times «{1}»
> Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «((03)|(07)|(AA)|[A-Z]{1})»
>    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(03)»
>       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(03)»
>          Match the characters “03” literally «03»
>    Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(07)»
>       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «(07)»
>          Match the characters “07” literally «07»
>    Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(AA)»
>       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 5 «(AA)»
>          Match the characters “AA” literally «AA»
>    Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[A-Z]{1}»
>       Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{1}»
>          Exactly 1 times «{1}»
> Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 6 «([A-Z]{2})»
>    Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{2}»
>       Exactly 2 times «{2}»
> ```

Comment: Agreed, the $'s should be the problem.